# Element not appearing on scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make an element appear once you've scrolled to a portion of the page but I seem to be struggling to make the element actually appear.

The code adds the class when you've scrolled to 200 but the element doesn't appear. Any suggestions?

```
window.onscroll = function() {

 scrollAppear()

};

function scrollAppear() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    document.getElementById("dimSum").className = "appear";
} else {
    document.getElementById("dimSum").className = "hidden";
}
}
```

This is the css

```
.dimsum {
  padding:40%;
  background-image: url(../images/dimSum.gif);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:350px;
}

.appear {

  opacity:0;
}

.hidden {

  opacity: 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with my actual image classname disappearing! Thank you guys!

Comment: Write the problem and mark it as solved, perhaps another user has the same problem in the future ;)